# React - Open a html page on a new tab with images and barcode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

in our react application we are trying to print an invoice on click of a button in new tab so that user can print them.
For the invoice data, am calling an api which give's me a full html page with image tag for logo and barcode as well, i have opened the page in a new tab. But the images and barcode are not displaying since am opening in a new tab. **The path mentioned below is where i keep the js and img in the project folder**. I can understand why they are not displaying, but is there any way to display them. Kindly share your suggestions

My response from api looks like below(have shown necessary parts only) and
code for opening them in new tab, receipt is the state object in which am setting the whole html content, i received from api

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 ..
 <script src="assets/js/barcode.min.js"></script>
 ..
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" />
..
 </html>
useEffect(()=>{
  if(receipt){
    let newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.write(receipt);
   }
},[receipt])
```

Comment: What does your receipt html look like?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
..
<script src="assets/js/barcode.min.js"></script>
..
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" />
..
</html>
skipped the other html parts... the relative path is where i have placed the img and js file in our react project inside src folder

Comment: there's a good chance that the "relative" path is not correct due to the way you are loading the html. Just use JavaScript to build an absolute url and use that instead.